# What is a basic setup of MyFaces Trinidad on a JSF 2.0 Project?

Tags: java, ajax, jsf-2, myfaces, trinidad

I have a JSF 2.0 project with MyFaces Trinidad 2.0.1 components, i have created some forms using trinidad components, but some components that use ajax don't render as expected or like in the [showcase](http://example.irian.at/trinidad-components-showcase-2012061803/faces/pages/demoStart.xhtml) or are non-responsive, The Tree component doesn't expand and the Tabbed Panel shows the content but doesn't render the Tab Control.The date picker also. Firebug doesn't show any JavaScript errors. Thank You

Im using Eclipse Indingo 3.7.2, Java EE 6, and Glassfish 3.1.2

[Screenshot](http://www.beatscent.co.za/res/form2.PNG)

Comment: Did you surround your components with a `tr:form`?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried starting a project with [Trinidad's Maven archetype](http://myfaces.apache.org/build-tools/archetypes/myfaces-archetype-trinidad20/index.html)?

> Use the following maven command and then select myfaces-archetype-trinidad20 from the options.

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=http://myfaces.apache.org
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using one of `<tr:document>`, `<trh:head>` or `<h:head>`?

[Here is a JSF2 tutorial that mentions that `<f:ajax>` support requires `<h:head>`](http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/pdf/jsf/jsf2/JSF2-Getting-Started.pdf). I would not be surprised if the ajax support for Trinidad components required something similar.